# How to use CPPFlow with giving a .txt as input

Tags: c++, tensorflow2.0

I recently used cppflow on VS 2019 on Windows 10.

My original data is data in 4 columns per row. I want to use neural network to classify precipitation particles. I have trained and saved my model (.pb) on python. Because it is text data in .txt, and the example described in the cppflow document uses pictures as input, I would like to ask what is the function of cppflow input in .txt text?

Answer (score 0):

Read the `.txt` file into a `std::vector` then convert into a `cppflow::tensor`.